# String Contains certain text

Tags: vba, excel

In my code I am looking for file which name include `bcst` but my code is not working. How can I make it work?

```
   For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ana = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Burak\Desktop\2MacroDegerlendirme.xlsm").Sheets("Sayfa1") 'Hangi sayfaya alınacak?   
    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
    Str = myFile.Name        
        If InStr(Str, "bcst") >= 0 Then
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Dir` with `"*bcst*"` as the file name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subscript out of range mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942098/subscript-out-of-range-mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking only at this portion of the code, I'm guessing the error is in

`If InStr(Str, "bcst") >= 0 Then`

InStr takes as first parameter the starting point of the search. Also it returns 0 if the pattern is not found, so it should be

`If InStr(1, Str, "bcst") > 0 Then`.

A prettiest alternative would be to use the `Like` operator:

`If Str Like "*bcst*" Then`

Comment: Also mind the "Option compare" setting etc., or transform all strings to lowercase first before comparing/finding.